# How should I fix the title bar of windows-terminal?

Tags: windows-terminal, title-bar

I have two users on my Windows 10 machine. I have installed Windows Terminal for both users. Below is a screenshot with showing what `wt.exe` looks like for both users.

I have a BAD (color: red) title bar for user '**win**' ( no tab titles nor the dropdown symbol, minimized, maximized), and a GOOD (color:green) title bar for user '**zviye**׳

Do you have any idea how to fix the BAD one???

[image: image file]

Comment: What has that user changed in `settings.json`? Check especially the value of `"theme"`. The easiest method might be to copy the good `settings.json` to the other user.

Comment: As @harrymc said, perhaps an issue with the Settings (but perhaps not).  I'd just move the "bad" `settings.json` off to another location and restart Windows Terminal.  It should be regenerated automatically.  If that doesn't work, we'll try to come up with some new ideas.  Reinstalling Windows Terminal would be my next recommended step, but I'm assuming you've tried that already?

Comment: I acted according to your suggestions and even reinstalled the windows terminal - but no success 